# Proxmox, LXC: problems Kubernetes setup

Tags: docker, kubernetes, lxc, proxmox

I am trying to get my single node Kubernetes cluster running inside an LXC container.

I am running a container with Debian-9.0-standard_9.7-1_amd64 image and docker. (For the setup of docker I followed: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/). I also enabled keyctl and Nesting.

I started following the Kubernetes setup tutorial but got stuck when I wanted to configure the network (Flannel) and initialize Kubernetes:

1. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/
2. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

[image: Kubernetes problems]

How can I proceed with this?

Comment: This might be useful. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/610

Comment: The guidelines you follow to setup your cluster are supposed to be applied on machines (this is clearly stated at the "Before you begin" sections). Is there a specific reason that you try to do this on a container?

Comment: @Mithilesh_Kunal that will fix the shared disk issue indeed, but still a couple issues :P

Comment: @tgogos I run proxmox, where LXC containers are more light then real vms. My thinking that I can use the resources better and more efficient in the lxc containers than in a vm

Comment: Just keep in mind that "[Containers Are Not Lightweight VMs](https://www.linuxfoundation.org/blog/2017/05/containers-are-not-lightweight-vms/)".

Comment: @tgogos thx I will keep it in mind, and if, in the end, there is no way to get it working inside an LXC container I will put it in a VM, but I want to give it a good try first...